# React Application with WordPress API - Image Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I can't figure out why this get request returns 404 error. I have tested the url in Postman! The title and excerpt works fine but the images gives an error. Any suggestions?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';

export class BlogItems extends Component { 
    state = {
        imgUrl: '',
        isLoaded: false
    }
    
    static propTypes = {
        blog: PropTypes.object.isRequired 
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const { featured_media} = this.props.blog;
      
        const getImageUrl = axios.get(`/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${featured_media}`);
      
        Promise.all([getImageUrl]).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({
                imgUrl: res[0].data.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url,
                isLoading: true
            })
            console.log('ok-3')
        });
    }

    render(){
        const { title,  excerpt } = this.props.blog;
        const { imgUrl} = this.state;

        return ( 
        <div>
            <img style={{width: '100%', height:'100%'}} src={imgUrl} alt={title.rendered} />
            <h3>{title.rendered}</h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: excerpt.rendered}} />
        </div>
        );
    } 


}

export default BlogItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a url error. The package.json was not reading "proxy":"http://localhost:8000". After adding it to the url it worked!